# python SyntaxError: encoding problem: windows-1255 with BOM

Tags: python, encoding, hebrew, windows-1255

That's my simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: windows-1255 -*-

str = "\u05dc\u05d9\u05d0\u05d5\u05e8"

print (str)
```

Could you tell me why I get this error?

```
python SyntaxError: encoding problem: windows-1255 with BOM
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You saved your simple code in an encoding that explicitly includes the BOM – for a 21st century editor, that'd most likely be UTF-8. There are no non-7-bit ASCII characters in your program, so the BOM is not necessary – but computers are famously dumb and do what you ask. But at the top of your script you declare you are using an entirely type of encoding – one that does *not* use a BOM – and so Python complains.

The fact that you have Unicode strings in your script, by the way, does not matter. It also happens when you save a simple

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: windows-1255 -*-

x
```

and try to run this.

It's sort of unexpected because to *parse* the encoding line at the top, Python already had to read and skip the BOM. But *that encoding* says that there should not have been a BOM, so there must – as Python correctly concludes – be an error somewhere.

Don't lie in the encoding line or save without BOM, and the problem disappears. If you cannot find out why your editor saves this way or are unable to find out how to properly save in the correct encoding, change the line at the top to

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

A very good discussion about the problems with different encodings and Unicode is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Python is pretty new to me. Could you please show me what is the correct script for my case? Thank you!

Comment: @user1074988: added the solution spelled out in more detail